# FBA (forms authentication) site - Export to Excel

Tags: sharepoint, excel, list, forms-authentication, export

Office Client Integration features are disabled by design on an FBA site. How would I export a list into Excel programmatically? Pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with FBA, but there are a number of libraries available that will create a native MS-Excel file.  Two of the most popular are:

- [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/) for Perl
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) for Java